# Is there a way to set the PATH variable when installing a electron app (cross-platform)

Tags: javascript, command-line, electron, cross-platform, electron-builder

## Question

I want to be able to open my electron app from the command-line like this:-

```
> app
```

and be able to pass command line arguments like:-

```
> app launch --file foo.txt
```

To accomplish the this, I tried to set the path variable to my app's executable. Is there something in-built in electron or electron-builder to accomplish this in a way that is cross-platform or at least for Windows and Linux separately?

## Other references

Visual studio code can be opened like `code file.js`, atom and [hyper.is](https://hyper.is) have similar functionality of opening the app from the command line.

## TL;DR

I want my users to be able open my electron app from the command line (like Visual studio code's `code` command), while passing custom arguments, if possible.